# local tomcat website request website on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat

We have a back-end website deployed on AWS. I deploy a front-end website in local tomcat and send a request to back-end website in order to get some object data with homemade soap api. Dose it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , literally you are trying to access a remote api from local environment. After the deployment in AWS do make sure the security groups allows the protocol and port number, to be communicated from remotely.

By default there ports are not allowed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to connect to a SOAP Webservice hosted in AWS. There is no reason it shouldn't be working, Only thing is you have to properly configure your AWS security groups attached to your backend server, to allow connections from your frontend website. Use front-end server port as the source ip in your security group. You might also have to allow outgoing connections from the network where your frontend server is hosted if it is protected by a firewall.